# Calculating percentage in matrix SSRS

Tags: matrix, ssrs-2008, percentage

I am trying to insert a calculated percentage column in my matrix and after searching here still having issues.

Fields in dataset: Cons_ID,Age,Region

**Row group:** Region

**Column group:** Age (Ranges)

**Details:** CountDistinct(Fields!Cons_ID.Value)

Any help appreciated.

Thx

Tom

EDIT:  [Image of ssrs setup](http://i48.tinypic.com/2ykhlqg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to get the percentage of details out of the total per group. Please be more specific if that's not what you are looking for. Here's an example of how you would reference the Age group overall to get a percentage:

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!Cons_ID.Value, "matrix1_Age")/CountDistinct(Fields!Cons_ID.Value, "matrix1_Region")
```

Comment: Hi Steven, that's exactly what I am looking to do. Now, in your example I had to substitute "Age" with "matrix1_Age" otherwise I was getting the error: _"The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox5’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function."_ After changing it it run fine but I had 100% in each of the columns. I was trying to attach a screen to illustrate the scenario but I cant as i am only new here...

Comment: OK, add a group specification in both of the statements. I'll edit my answer. Of course, change the group names to match yours.